# Problems with sendmessage and activating a vb6 form from a .net application

Tags: vb.net, api, vb6, migration, vb6-migration

I have compiled an old vb6 app into a dll. Eventually we will convert to .NET but for now I am trying to load the forms from the DLL. So far I have been able to load and see the vb6 form in .NET but I cannot activate the controls. So the setparent in the code below is working but the sendmessage and following code is not. By the way in debug mode this all works fine. It's only when I used the compiled dll that I have a problem.

My declare's are:

```
Private Shared Function SetParent(ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, _
          ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As Int32
End Function

Public Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" ( _
       ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
       ByVal wMsg As Int32, _
       ByVal wParam As Int32, _
       ByVal s As String _
       ) As Int32

 Private Shared Function SetForegroundWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
 End Function

 Private Shared Function LockWindowUpdate(ByVal hwndLock As IntPtr) As Boolean
 End Function
```

The code  I am using is as follows:

```
SetParent(mintFormHandle, Me.Handle.ToInt32)
SendMessage(mintFormHandle, WM_ACTIVATE, 1, IntPtr.Zero)
SetForegroundWindow(mintFormHandle)
LockWindowUpdate(0)

Me.Refresh()
```

Please no comments about old vb6 code. Yes in a perfect world a conversion would have been done years ago.

Comment: Not sure I understand "So far I have been able to load and see the vb6 form in .NET but I cannot activate the controls." - are the controls all disabled?

Comment: The whole vb6 form is frozen within the .net container. The container form is working fine.

Comment: frozen but you can see the controls?

Comment: What happens if you remove the call to the `LockWindowUpdate` function?